# Which styled in `mui` to use and what are their differences

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, material-ui, emotion

I've been using mui for a few weeks now and each example sees `styled` importing differently.
Some examples import from `@mui/material/styles` , others from `@mui/system` .

And in the documentation it only explains `@mui/system` . I would like to know the differences.

```js
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

const newButton = styled(Button)({
  boxShadow: 'none',
  textTransform: 'none',
  fontSize: 16,
  padding: '6px 12px'
});

// or
import { styled } from "@mui/system";

const newButton = styled(Button)({
  boxShadow: 'none',
  textTransform: 'none',
  fontSize: 16,
  padding: '6px 12px'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`@mui/material/styles`](https://mui.com/system/styles/basics/) is a legacy package. It is not compatible with [React.StrictMode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) and also won't work with React 18.

[`@mui/system`](https://mui.com/system/basics/) is the recommended alternative to the legacy package.

You can continue using `@mui/material/styles`, but at a certain point it may no longer be supported and will already limit you to older versions of React.